# Why am I getting intellisense in .cshtml comments and how to do I turn it off in VS2022 17.9.5?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Today, I'm seeing something new and strange in Visual Studio 2022 17.9.5.  When typing an html comment in a .cshtml file an intellisense like context menu appears with what look like html tags.  It's not helpful given since I'm typing a comment :-)  It's a distraction I'd like to eliminate.

[image]

I'm not sure which VS version this started in because I haven't done any coding for about about 3 months and I just updated VS to the latest version.  But I'm reasonably sure this wasn't happening in VS 3 months ago.

Why is this context menu being shown when typing a // html comment? And more importantly, how can I turn this off?

PS: After posting this question I've noticed VS provides that same intellisense content menu full of html tags when I'm typing javascript in a .cshtml file as well.  Intellisene in .cshtml files feels very broken.

Comment: Exact same problem here. I would describe it as disruptive because it tends to auto-replace whole sentences with html tags! It is broken, alright.

Comment: I’m seeing this disruptive replacement  behavior as well. I’m thinking of rolling back one VS update and hoping that will fix it for now.